# Iterate multiple lists and write down positions of specific repeating elements

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Let's say I have multiple lists as follow:

```
for i in range(len(vera)):
    print(vera[i].numbers)
```

and output is:

```
[6 6 7 6 6 6 8 6 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[6 7 6 8 6 6 6 6 6 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[6 6 6 6 6 6 7 8 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[7 6 6 9 6 7 6 8 8 1 1 1]
[7 6 8 8 6 6 6 6 8 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[6 8 6 6 6 6 6 6 8 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
[8 6 6 6 6 6 6 8 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

How can I store the positions of each 1 for every list as nested list such as:

```
[[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], ....]
```

Many thanks for some suggestions...

Comment: `[position for position,value in enumerate(vera[i].numbers) if value == 1]`

Comment: Can you confirm what is *vera* sample input list?  ~~~^^^ thinking about the same. ;-)

Comment: Are the *numbers* objects numpy arrays? If not, how are you getting that output? If yes, you really should make that clear in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of a double [`list` comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to achieve this:

```
[{position for position,value in enumerate(x.numbers) if value == 1} for x in vera]
```

Beware that is not good practice to iterate over the range, in this case you only needed the items in the list.

here is a sample code to check my code (the attribute isn't there because it's a list)

```
from pprint import pprint
vera = [
[6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 8, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[6, 7, 6, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[7, 6, 6, 9, 6, 7, 6, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1,],
[7, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[6, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,],
]
pprint([{position for position,value in enumerate(x) if value == 1} for x in vera])
```

Output shown:

```
[{9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16},
 {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17},
 {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16},
 {9, 10, 11},
 {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17},
 {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22},
 {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}]
```

**NOTE**: If you are using numpy, you can also apply the [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) function with a list of [`np.array`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html)s.

here is a sample code to test what said before:

```
import numpy as np
from pprint import pprint

vera = [[6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 6, 8, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,],
[6, 7, 6, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,],
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,],
[7, 6, 6, 9, 6, 7, 6, 8, 8, 1, 1, 1,],
[7, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,],
[6, 8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,],
[8, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
]

vera = map(np.array,vera)
pprint(list(map(lambda arr:set(np.where(arr==1)[0]),vera)))
```

Output:

```
[{9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16},
 {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17},
 {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16},
 {9, 10, 11},
 {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17},
 {9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22},
 {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}]
```

**NOTE**: i'm using `set`s because the numbers are unique (and optimizations that comes with sets) this actually doesn't change at all the result without `set`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
[list(pd.Series(l)[pd.Series(l).eq(1)].index) for l in vera]
```

Output:

```
[[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
 [9, 10, 11],
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]]
```